# google distance matrix api is not working on inmotion server

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I am facing very weird issue, google distance matrix api is working on all server but not working on inmotion server. Could anyone help me to sort this issue.

I am using php and below is the standard code. This is not printing anything while same code is working everywhere. I tried with specific ip, specefic domain setting in google console api but did not find anything working on this server

$data = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&key=your_key");
$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);
print_r($data);

Comment: Try to use different API key -- I don't know why but it works on my end.

Comment: Thanks Adiono, for your comment. It is already sorted... It was server issue, server was blocking API access...